# find time conflicts between two dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on a query that should find lunch times between two dates.
for example, lunch time is between 14:00 PM and 15:30 PM.
and dates are: '2016-06-09 10:00:00.000' and '2016-06-11 10:00:00.000'
lunch time occures two times between these dates.
and another examples:

```
'2016-06-09 15:00:00.000' and '2016-06-11 10:00:00.000' : 2 Times
'2016-06-09 17:00:00.000' and '2016-06-11 10:00:00.000' : 1 Time
'2016-06-09 13:00:00.000' and '2016-06-11 15:00:00.000' : 3 Times
```

but I can never do it :(

Comment: Please, show us what have you tried.

Comment: I wrote a while adds minutes to `@date1` and goes to `@date2`, every time check if it's TIME is between start lunch time and end lunch time, if it is true, `@CountedLunches` will increase, but a bit variable changes to prevent double increase for a lunch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this and make tweeks according to your requirements:

```
DECLARE @date1 DATETIME = '2016-06-09 08:30:00.000';
DECLARE @date2 DATETIME = '2016-06-13 18:00:00.000';
DECLARE @lunchStart DATETIME = '2016-06-13 14:00:00.000';
DECLARE @lunchEnd DATETIME = '2016-06-13 15:30:00.000';
DECLARE @output INT = 0;

SELECT @output = DATEDIFF(DAY, @date1, @date2)
IF DATEPART(HOUR, @date1) > DATEPART(HOUR, @lunchStart) OR (DATEPART(HOUR, @date1) = DATEPART(HOUR, @lunchStart) AND DATEPART(MINUTE, @date1) <= DATEPART(MINUTE, @lunchStart))
    SET @output = @output - 1

IF DATEPART(HOUR, @date2) < DATEPART(HOUR, @lunchEnd) OR (DATEPART(HOUR, @date2) = DATEPART(HOUR, @lunchEnd) AND DATEPART(MINUTE, @date2) = DATEPART(MINUTE, @lunchEnd))
    SET @output = @output - 1

PRINT @output
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but you are using DATEPART(HOUR,...)
and what about minutes?!

Comment: Edited the answer for minute-consideration too :)

Comment: thank you again, I changed it and it worked, Thank you again

Answer (score 4):

This seems to work:

```
declare @t table (StartAt datetime not null,EndBefore datetime not null)
insert into @t(StartAt,EndBefore) values
('2016-06-09T15:00:00.000','2016-06-11T10:00:00.000'),
('2016-06-09T17:00:00.000','2016-06-11T10:00:00.000'),
('2016-06-09T13:00:00.000','2016-06-11T15:00:00.000')

;With Dates as (
    select MIN(DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day,0,StartAt),0)) as ADate
    from @t
    union all
    select DATEADD(day,1,ADate) from Dates
    where exists (select * from @t where EndBefore > DATEADD(day,1,ADate))
), Lunches as (
    select DATEADD(minute,(14*60),ADate) as StartAt,
           DATEADD(minute,(15*60+30),ADate) as EndBefore
    from Dates
)
select
    *,(select COUNT(*) from Lunches l
       where l.StartAt < t.EndBefore and t.StartAt < l.EndBefore)
from @t t
```

Where we used two CTEs to (a) derive all relevant Dates, and (b) from the dates, compute all possible lunch times, before finally just finding all lunches that *overlap* the original periods.

Result:

```
StartAt                 EndBefore               
----------------------- ----------------------- -----------
2016-06-09 15:00:00.000 2016-06-11 10:00:00.000 2
2016-06-09 17:00:00.000 2016-06-11 10:00:00.000 1
2016-06-09 13:00:00.000 2016-06-11 15:00:00.000 3
```

Note - many people overcomplicate trying to work out a definition of overlaps. I'm using a simple definition here and usually the only thing that might require alteration is deciding on whether to use `<` or `<=`, which depends on whether you consider two periods that *abut* but otherwise do not cover the same time periods to be overlapped.

So here, you might want to change the definitions if you're unhappy with the answers the above query produces when you're querying for periods that *start* at exactly 15:30 or *end* at exactly 14:00.

Comment: thank you for your correct answer and your description, but I can only select one answer as correct answer.